# ADL, Ordinary lookup and Dependent function call not working oO

Tags: c++

Here is simple code presented which should have worked according to c++ standard **I believe** :

```
template<typename T> 
void foo(T x) 
{ 
    bar(x); 
    void bar(int);
} 
 
void bar(int)  { } 
 
int main() 
{ 
    foo(0); 
}
```

Error comes as from GCC 4.7 as:

> ‘bar’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found
> by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation

But in the C++ standard it's written. § 14.6.4.2 :

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the
> candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1,
> 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> **— For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1)** or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), **only function declarations from the template definition context are found.**

I may be have got the wrong impression of what's written, can anyone please correct me here?

Answer (score 0):

You should just move the declaration of 'bar' to the top.  Because at the point where the template is defined (not instantiated), before 'bar' is invoked, it hasn't be declared.

Comment: I could've done that and it had worked. But why is that not working? , At the point of instantiation it should have been resolved since it's dependent call

Comment: Well, having read your snippet of the standard, I don't think it conflicts with what I've said, nor with GCC's rejection of your code.  I think what you've presented is not proper C++.

Comment: So all in all you mean that ordinary lookup is not performed on dependent calls at the point of instantiation ?

Comment: I guess so.  What I really mean is that when I look at that code, it looks wrong, and reading your snippet of the standard doesn't change my mind.  :)

Comment: Please consider including statements from c++ standard backing your guesses :)

Comment: @M3taSpl0it your problem is that you are relying on a function declaration inside a template *function*.

Comment: I just checked the code with intel compiler and it works , though clang and gcc rejects it .